# Finding the datatype of AttributeValue

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to serialize the dynamodb datastructure into JSON and CSV after some processing in the middle tier. I would like to create a generic method which can take Map(String, AttributeValue) as the argument and convert it into JSON.

So, i would like to understand the datatype of the AttributeValue - String, Number, String[] and Number[] to do that. Is there an API to find that out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the four available [Amazon DynamoDB Data Types](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataModel.html#DataModelDataTypes) are defined as follows:

> **String** - Strings are Unicode with UTF8 binary encoding. There is no limit to the string size when you assign it to an attribute except
>   when the attribute is part of the primary key. [...]
>
> **Number** - Numbers are positive or negative exact-value decimals and integers. A number can have up to 38 digits of precision after the
>   decimal point, and can be between 10^-128 to 10^+126. The
>   representation in Amazon DynamoDB is of variable length. [...]
>
> **String and Number Sets** - Amazon DynamoDB also supports both Number Sets and String Sets.
>   [...] Note that, because it is a
>   set, the values in the set must be unique. String Sets and Number Sets
>   are not ordered; the order of the values returned in a set is not
>   preserved.

You will need to specify or handle these data types in various API calls anyway, e.g. for *KeySchema* in [CreateTable](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_CreateTable.html) or *Item* in [GetItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_GetItem.html), and even for *AttributesToGet* in [Query](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html) or [Scan](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Scan.html), so the information should actually be available already before you receive an API call response?!

Comment: Sorry for not explaining it in detail.
I am using GetItemRequest (Java Low-Level API), which returns a Map of String & AttributeValue. I am trying to find out the datatype of the data in AttributeValue, to serialize it into JSON. i.e. data in AttributeValue will be serialized with double quotes, if it is String and without double quotes, if it is a Number.